# Sample Xamarin project fail build in VSTS

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, xamarin.android, azure-devops

I'm trying to build this, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started/,  project with VSTS. Code is checked in, default build configuration used. But for unknown reason, it fails. It seems that all code and assemblies is downloaded:

```
...
2016-10-31T14:31:13.1891941Z C:\a\1\s\FirstXamarinApp\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android.1.1.0\lib\MonoAndroid:
2016-10-31T14:31:13.1891941Z Getting SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll
2016-10-31T14:31:13.9442737Z ##[section]Finishing: Get Sources
2016-10-31T14:31:13.9462739Z ##[section]Starting: Xamarin component restore $/Mobile Playground/FirstXamarinApp
2016-10-31T14:31:13.9732734Z ==============================================================================
2016-10-31T14:31:13.9732734Z Task         : Xamarin Component Restore
2016-10-31T14:31:13.9732734Z Description  : Restores Xamarin components for the specified solution
2016-10-31T14:31:13.9732734Z Version      : 0.1.8
2016-10-31T14:31:13.9732734Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2016-10-31T14:31:13.9732734Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786653)
2016-10-31T14:31:13.9732734Z ==============================================================================
2016-10-31T14:31:14.7788257Z [command]C:\a\_tasks\XamarinComponentRestore_ff50fc97-da8c-4683-b014-34c15315ee5f\0.1.8\xpkg\xamarin-component.exe restore -u [removed] -p [removed] C:/a/1/s/FirstXamarinApp
2016-10-31T14:31:15.0028479Z INFO (restore): Computed cookie jar path: C:\Users\buildguest\.xamarin-credentials
2016-10-31T14:31:16.2730908Z INFO (login): Computed cookie jar path: C:\Users\buildguest\.xamarin-credentials
2016-10-31T14:31:16.2800907Z INFO (login): Computed cookie jar path: C:\Users\buildguest\.xamarin-credentials
2016-10-31T14:31:16.2800907Z INFO (login): Credentials successfully stored.
2016-10-31T14:31:16.2830906Z ERROR (login): C:/a/1/s/FirstXamarinApp does not exist.
2016-10-31T14:31:16.2970912Z ##[error]xamarin-component.exe failed with error: C:\a\_tasks\XamarinComponentRestore_ff50fc97-da8c-4683-b014-34c15315ee5f\0.1.8\xpkg\xamarin-component.exe failed with return code: 1
2016-10-31T14:31:16.2970912Z ##[error]xamarin-component.exe failed with error: C:\a\_tasks\XamarinComponentRestore_ff50fc97-da8c-4683-b014-34c15315ee5f\0.1.8\xpkg\xamarin-component.exe failed with return code: 1
2016-10-31T14:31:16.3030909Z ##[section]Finishing: Xamarin component restore $/Mobile Playground/FirstXamarinApp
2016-10-31T14:31:16.3030909Z ##[section]Starting: Publish Artifact: drop
2016-10-31T14:31:16.3050910Z ==============================================================================
2016-10-31T14:31:16.3050910Z Task         : Publish Build Artifacts
2016-10-31T14:31:16.3050910Z Description  : Publish Build artifacts to the server or a file share
2016-10-31T14:31:16.3050910Z Version      : 1.0.38
2016-10-31T14:31:16.3050910Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2016-10-31T14:31:16.3050910Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708390)
2016-10-31T14:31:16.3050910Z ==============================================================================
2016-10-31T14:31:16.4940955Z ##[error]Publish build artifacts failed with error: Not found PathtoPublish: C:\a\1\b\Release
2016-10-31T14:31:16.4980941Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish Artifact: drop
2016-10-31T14:31:16.4990982Z ##[section]Starting: Post Job Cleanup
2016-10-31T14:31:16.5110937Z ##[section]Finishing: Post Job Cleanup
2016-10-31T14:31:16.5110937Z ##[section]Finishing: Build
```

To me it seems that the everything is downloaded to c:\a\1\s. But later, the error is thrown on

> ERROR (login): C:/a/1/s/FirstXamarinApp does not exist.

'\' has been replaced by '/'. Can this be the reason?

I haven't done anything special with the build steps. Just referenced the solution file, project file, added username and password for Xamarin and set Java to version 8 instead of custom.

In Visual Studio, the project builds just fine.

Comment: This definitely looks like a potential pathing issue. I'm curious if you remove the Xamarin Component restore step and changed those items to NuGet instead if that would resolve your issue.

Comment: Did you try to manually install the xamarin components?

Comment: @JonDouglas; it seems that the variable "Project" that was originally set to  "$/Mobile Playground/FirstXamarinApp/playground/playground.csproj" was the reason for the problem. When changes to "**/playground.csproj", the build continued. Interestingly, I chose the path by using the "browser" function, so it's a bit weird that this didn't work.

Comment: @xleon; how can you manually install the xamarin components on a shared build agent with VSTS?

Comment: @sonstabo you are totally right. I misread the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the variable "Project" that was originally set to "$/Mobile Playground/FirstXamarinApp/playground/playground.csproj" was the reason for the problem. When changed to "**/playground.csproj", the build continued.

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, you specified a folder path `$/Mobile Playground/FirstXamarinApp` in **Path to Solution**. I could reproduce your issue if I specified a folder path like screenshot below:

[image]

> To get rid of this issue, you need to specify the solution path like
>   screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Cece. As I commented above, I managed to fix this by changing the project setting.

Comment: @sonstabo Wow~It seems you have found the root cause when I tested your issue. You may add an answer here which will be beneficial to other community members.:-)

Comment: True @Cece :) I'll do that.